# Prevent buffer flush in a TTY port on new line character

Tags: linux

I'm trying to write 512B to a ttyACM port (a cdc composite device) with C.
The problem is that the Linux driver in my machine (Ubuntu 18.04) is sending the data in chunks, every line break (0x0A) creates a new chunk.
How can I prevent it? I tried using cfmakeraw function without success.
This is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <termios.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE_ACM 512

int main() {
FILE *acm, *file;
unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE_ACM];

struct termios termios_p;

if((acm = fopen( "/dev/ttyACMX" ,"wb")) == NULL ) {
    printf("ERROR\n");
    return -1;
  }

  if((file = fopen( "/path/to/img/file" ,"rb")) == NULL ) {
    printf("ERROR\n");
    return -1;
  }

  cfmakeraw(&termios_p);
  tcsetattr( fileno(acm),TCSANOW , &termios_p);

  /*read data from file*/
  if(fread(buffer, 1 , BUFFER_SIZE_ACM, file) == NULL) {
      printf("ERROR\n");
      return -1;
    }
   /*write data*/
   fwrite(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE_ACM, acm);
   fflush(acm);
   return 0;
}
```

If the data read from the file has no 0x0A bytes, it is written in one 512B chunk.
Unwanted behavior Example:
512B content:

```
00000000  65 e4 9f 40 a2 37 4f b6  d2 d0 ae 99 ac e2 a4 22
00000010  8f 99 b4 45 4a 2e a4 d1  99 22 23 e7 e0 d2 06 3d
00000020  72 92 ce af 25 ea 7e 59  d7 56 01 0a be 4d 91 13
00000030  b0 4b 33 62 f1 84 62 30  56 a0 2e 2a fb 07 70 e7
00000040  9a c9 64 62 02 15 19 e5  a1 f7 85 53 8b 94 d7 e7
00000050  8e b8 7e 06 0c 9a 53 90  77 60 ff 9f e8 65 87 bd
00000060  ad 8a 2c 70 a5 12 f9 d5  44 48 7d 47 79 d0 83 63
00000070  96 f3 d0 67 f0 4f 49 63  4a 5e 6e 10 52 3f 09 c5
00000080  cd 9e 2c c2 aa 55 9e 31  ed 6d e5 a9 2a 1f 4c 72
00000090  d2 c8 96 02 3a 8a 4a 14  9b 26 af 99 78 fb 15 e3
000000a0  52 5f 53 d1 c0 21 59 a2  00 0c 6f 5b ae 15 f2 19
000000b0  dc d3 81 e3 11 ed 68 90  0a 18 a1 41 ad 60 b6 1f
000000c0  5b 54 98 93 04 1e 00 8e  e2 fc 37 9c e8 c2 99 76
000000d0  a5 8b c2 f7 43 60 7a 39  17 b3 8b 20 31 02 c4 0d
000000e0  86 2b 5c ac 4a 1f 4e b3  07 7b 63 5f 81 ad a5 b3
000000f0  ef 82 06 60 46 0a 24 7b  7f 75 f5 72 d4 b0 47 55
00000100  06 f9 5f c9 9e d2 d7 bf  6f 39 9f 0c 37 11 35 12
00000110  4a 2c c6 8b 5a a8 a9 a5  ce bb eb e9 66 81 57 66
00000120  e2 5c 0f 85 d9 de 59 1c  0e df 15 e7 08 30 5d ca
00000130  a7 33 7e 69 d4 39 67 18  d7 55 b3 e3 1e 9a 11 b9
00000140  1f 5e fe 98 34 fb f3 30  7f dd d9 29 dc 8c 16 50
00000150  1a 2b 48 00 5d 62 6e 10  e4 c5 1d 59 5d b4 6c 1a
00000160  25 32 5f 5f 9b 1b 8f d4  ce 94 9c e6 76 3d fc a6
00000170  45 2a dd 2f f2 8e 20 d0  69 66 1b 5e 9d f9 26 6c
00000180  bc 41 12 cb 10 2f f3 06  24 7a 2d 6d f2 8d 9b bd
00000190  6c a5 6a a5 9a 68 b1 be  7a e6 b9 12 aa 43 51 d6
000001a0  20 1c c3 0a 0b 33 4c 9a  e4 94 06 02 7e 79 f4 6c
000001b0  2b e4 26 65 71 b4 b9 1d  8a aa df 77 9a ae fd 05
000001c0  5f 9d 6e 18 d9 a0 ed d1  68 80 1d fe bc 11 89 21
000001d0  30 d9 ab e2 83 6a d4 59  12 43 13 08 2f 57 37 35
000001e0  cf 47 b3 7d 54 a1 a9 6d  a8 ce a9 c2 64 8e 4b c9
000001f0  0f e4 d6 f8 13 54 25 89  83 6f e7 cf b4 6f 87 bb
00000200
```

This is written in 5 different chunks:

```
   65 E4 9F 40 A2 37 4F B6    D2 D0 AE 99 AC E2 A4 22 
   8F 99 B4 45 4A 2E A4 D1    99 22 23 E7 E0 D2 06 3D
   72 92 CE AF 25 EA 7E 59    D7 56 01 0A
```

```
   BE 4D 91 13 B0 4B 33 62    F1 84 62 30 56 A0 2E 2A 
   FB 07 70 E7 9A C9 64 62    02 15 19 E5 A1 F7 85 53
   8B 94 D7 E7 8E B8 7E 06    0C 9A 53 90 77 60 FF 9F
   E8 65 87 BD AD 8A 2C 70    A5 12 F9 D5 44 48 7D 47 
   79 D0 83 63 96 F3 D0 67    F0 4F 49 63 4A 5E 6E 10
   52 3F 09 C5 CD 9E 2C C2    AA 55 9E 31 ED 6D E5 A9
   2A 1F 4C 72 D2 C8 96 02    3A 8A 4A 14 9B 26 AF 99
   78 FB 15 E3 52 5F 53 D1    C0 21 59 A2 00 0C 6F 5B
   AE 15 F2 19 DC D3 81 E3    11 ED 68 90 0A
```

```
   18 A1 41 AD 60 B6 1F 5B    54 98 93 04 1E 00 8E E2
   FC 37 9C E8 C2 99 76 A5    8B C2 F7 43 60 7A 39 17
   B3 8B 20 31 02 C4 0D 86    2B 5C AC 4A 1F 4E B3 07
   7B 63 5F 81 AD A5 B3 EF    82 06 60 46 0A
```

```
   24 7B 7F 75 F5 72 D4 B0    47 55 06 F9 5F C9 9E D2
   D7 BF 6F 39 9F 0C 37 11    35 12 4A 2C C6 8B 5A A8
   A9 A5 CE BB EB E9 66 81    57 66 E2 5C 0F 85 D9 DE
   59 1C 0E DF 15 E7 08 30    5D CA A7 33 7E 69 D4 39
   67 18 D7 55 B3 E3 1E 9A    11 B9 1F 5E FE 98 34 FB 
   F3 30 7F DD D9 29 DC 8C    16 50 1A 2B 48 00 5D 62 
   6E 10 E4 C5 1D 59 5D B4    6C 1A 25 32 5F 5F 9B 1B
   8F D4 CE 94 9C E6 76 3D    FC A6 45 2A DD 2F F2 8E
   20 D0 69 66 1B 5E 9D F9    26 6C BC 41 12 CB 10 2F
   F3 06 24 7A 2D 6D F2 8D    9B BD 6C A5 6A A5 9A 68
   B1 BE 7A E6 B9 12 AA 43    51 D6 20 1C C3 0A
```

```
   0B 33 4C 9A E4 94 06 02    7E 79 F4 6C 2B E4 26 65
   71 B4 B9 1D 8A AA DF 77    9A AE FD 05 5F 9D 6E 18 
   D9 A0 ED D1 68 80 1D FE    BC 11 89 21 30 D9 AB E2 
   83 6A D4 59 12 43 13 08    2F 57 37 35 CF 47 B3 7D 
   54 A1 A9 6D A8 CE A9 C2    64 8E 4B C9 0F E4 D6 F8 
   13 54 25 89 83 6F E7 CF    B4 6F 87 BB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the non-buffered `write(2)` (and `open(2)`, etc) instead of the stdio `fwrite(3)`. By default, stdio will line-buffer writes to ttys.

Or if you really need to use stdio, make it unbuffered with `setvbuf(fileno(acm), 0, _IONBUF, 0)`.

BTW: you should first get the actual termios params with `tcgetattr(3)`, modify them with `cfmakeraw(3)`, and *then* set them with `tcsetattr(3)`. And CHECK the return value of all those functions -- it's most likely that `tcsetattr(3)` FAILED (because `termios_p` contained whatever garbage was on the stack), but you have no way to know it.

Also notice that `tcsetattr(3)` will succeed if it was able to perform *any* (not *all*) of the changes requested, so you should call `tcgetattr(3)` again with another termios struct and compare its content with that of the one used with `tcsetattr(3)`.

Comment: Hi,The code was just an example to demonstrate the issue. My actual code does checks the return values, and does uses tcsetattr. Anyway, setvbuf fixed the problem , thanks!!!